# Hamburger menu using nested ItemsControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, model, controls

I'm working on implementing a hamburger menu in C#/XAML using WPF, and I'm not sure if the way I'm going about it is correct.

The end goal is to have a list of parent items, each of which can have a list of child items. *This will be in a vertical menu control along the left side of the screen*. For example:

```
Parent 1
    Child 1
Parent 2
    Child 1
    Child 2
    Child 3
```

Right now I have the following:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding HamburgerModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding HamburgerModel.ParentItems}" Foreground="White" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" MouseDown="ItemsControl_MouseDown">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <GroupBox Header="{Binding Text}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems.ChildItems}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </GroupBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class HamburgerMenuModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ParentItem> ParentItems { get; set; }
}

public class ParentItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ChildItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChildItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public long Offset { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, **does this approach make sense? Are there any notable errors or flaws?**
Any pointers on which direction to take next would be most helpful.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad for me. You might want to take a look at TreeView, since this is usually used for Parent/Child as itemscontrol. btw: If you ask for a review, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: @jHilscher Thanks, I didn't know about TreeView. That'll be super helpful!